# Match Data constructor functions

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm trying to match data constructors in a generic way, so that any Task of a certain type will be executed.

```
data Task = TaskTypeA Int | TaskTypeB (Float,Float)

genericTasks :: StateLikeMonad s
genericTasks = do
   want (TaskTypeA 5)

   TaskTypeA #> \input -> do 
       want (TaskTypeB (1.2,4.3))
       runTaskTypeA input

   TaskTypeB #> \(x,y) -> runTaskTypeB x y

main = runTask genericTasks
```

In this, the `genericTasks` function goes through the do-instructions, building a list of stuff to do from `want` handled by some sort of state monad, and a list of ways to do it, via the `(#>)` function. The `runTask` function will run the genericTasks, use the resulting list of to-do and how-to-do, and do the computations.

However, I'm having quite some trouble figuring out how to extract the "type" (`TaskTypeA,B`) from (#>), such that one can call it later. If you do a `:t TaskTypeA`, you get a `Int -> Task`.

I.e., **How to write `(#>)`?**

I'm also not entirely confident that it's possible to do what I'm thinking here in such a generic way. For reference, I'm trying to build something similar to the `Shake` library, where `(#>)` is similar to `(*>)`. However Shake uses a String as the argument to `(*>)`, so the matching is done entirely using String matching. I'd like to do it without requiring strings.

Comment: This is my first time having a go at SO, so let me know if anything needs clarification. I'm pretty new at Haskell as well, but this has had me stumped for longer than usual -- Unfortunately that often means its not totally feasible the way I imagine it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, it's not possible to write `(#>)` as you have specified. The only time a data constructor acts as a pattern is when it is in pattern *position*, namely, appearing as a parameter to a function

```
f (TaskTypeA z) = ...
```

as one of the alternatives of a `case` statement

```
case tt of
    TaskTypeA z -> ...
```

or in a monadic or pattern binding

```
do TaskTypeA z <- Just tt
   return z
```

When used in value position (e.g. as an argument to a function), it loses its patterny nature and becomes a regular function.  That means, unfortunately, that you cannot abstract over patterns this easily.

There is, however, a simple formalization of patterns:

```
type Pattern d a = d -> Maybe a
```

It's a little bit of work to make them.

```
taskTypeA :: Pattern Task Int
taskTypeA (TaskTypeA z) = Just z
taskTypeA _ = Nothing
```

If you also need need to use the constructor "forwards" (i.e. `a -> d`), then you could pair the two together (plus some functions to work with it):

```
data Constructor d a = Constructor (a -> d) (d -> Maybe a)

apply :: Constructor d a -> a -> d
apply (Constructor f _) = f

match :: Constructor d a -> d -> Maybe a
match (Constructor _ m) = m

taskTypeA :: Constructor Task Int
taskTypeA = Constructor TaskTypeA $ \case TaskTypeA z -> Just z
                                          _ -> Nothing
```

This is known as a "prism", and (a very general form of) it is implemented in [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.2/doc/html/Control-Lens-Prism.html).

There are advantages to using an abstraction like this -- namely, that you can construct prisms which may have more structure than data types are allowed to (e.g. `d` can be a function type), and you can write functions that operate on constructors, composing simpler ones  to make more complex ones generically.

If you are using plain data types, though, it is a pain to have to implement the `Constructor` objects for each constructor like I did for `TaskTypeA` above.  If you have a lot of these to work with, you can use [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell) to write your boilerplate for you.  The necessary Template Haskell routine is [already implemented](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.2/doc/html/Control-Lens-TH.html#v%3amakePrisms) in lens -- it may be worth it to learn how to use the lens library because of that.  (But it can be a bit daunting to navigate)

(Style note: the second `Constructor` above and its two helper functions can be written equivalently using a little trick:

```
data Constructor d a = Constructor { apply :: a -> d, match :: d -> Maybe a }
```

)

With this abstraction in place, it is now possible to write `(#>)`.  A simple example would be

```
(#>) :: Constructor d a -> (a -> State d ()) -> State d ()
cons #> f = do
    d <- get
    case match cons d of
        Nothing -> return ()
        Just a  -> f a
```

or perhaps something more sophisticated, depending on what precisely you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm working through what you explained, but I don't quite get the notation for the 2nd `taskTypeA` constructor, specifically: `$\case TaskTypeA z -> Just z, _ -> Nothing`. I'm guessing you are paraphrasing, but I'm not quite sure what you meant exactly.

Comment: @maximilian Oh, that's [`LambdaCase`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html), a GHC extension.  Could have written `Constructor TaskTypeA $ \x -> case x of ...` instead.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out how to write the 2nd "constructor", but when I compile, It doesn't take any arguments? I'm not quite sure how to use this 2nd constructor to do something -- I guess I should pattern match against it? (in order to get the functions out of it to do something?

Comment: Yes -- I realized that a bit late. Once I rewrote it to use an "x", I realized there was probably an extension to get rid of the superfluous 'x'.

Comment: @maximilian I edited the answer to introduce some functions for working with `Constructor`

Comment: Ok. So I mostly the individual steps above, but I'm still at a loss, how I would use this to try and write something like `(#>)`?

Comment: Thanks for the last example. I think I see how I could make this work now.